# WebApi 2 Odata Controller encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, odata, asp.net-web-api2

How can I adjust WebApi2 Odata Controller, to serialize data the same way the ApiController does? and why does it replace non Unicode characters from "č" to "\u010d" ?

For example

```
 public class PacientaiController : ODataController
    { ...
     // GET: odata/Pacientai
        [Queryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 8)]
        public  IHttpActionResult GetPacientai(ODataQueryOptions<Pacientas> queryOptions)
        {
```

Results in

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://localhost:13248/odata/$metadata#Pacientai",
    "value": [{
        "Id": 1147146,
        "Vardas": "Edgaras",
        "Pavarde": "Me\u010dkauskas",
        "AK": "12341412341",
        "GimimoData": "1986-01-16T00:00:00"
    }]
}
```

And If I change the controller to ApiController Like this

```
 public class PacientaiController : ApiController
    { ...
        [Queryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 8)]
        public  IHttpActionResult GetPacientai()
        {
```

The result is this :

```
{
    "Id": 1147146,
    "Vardas": "Edgaras",
    "Pavarde": "Mečkauskas",
    "AK": "12341412341",
    "GimimoData": "1986-01-16T00:00:00",
}
```

Note the Field : Pavarde!

Comment: Link to CodePlex issue : https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2039

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could write a message handler:

```
public class StringRewriter : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter;

    static StringRewriter()
    {
        formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.Content == null || response.Content.Headers.ContentType == null ||
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType != "application/json")
        {
            return response;
        }

        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var token = JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));

        var content = new ObjectContent<JToken>(token, formatter);
        foreach (var header in response.Content.Headers)
        {
            content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        response.Content = content;

        return response;
    }
}
```

And add that to WebApiConfig:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new StringRewriter());
```